# Insert unicode characters in React

Tags: reactjs, unicode

I want to use this arrow in my React app: U+02197.
I read [this article](http://mts.io/) that explains why how to force a unicode symbol to render **as text insted of emoji**.
Infat I want that the symbol is alway rendered as text.

I try:

```
<a href="...">U+02197</a>
```

But it is rendered as string "U+02197". How can I visualize the char?
I try also:

```
U+2197 &U+2197; U+02197 U+02197; &U+02197; \U+02197 \u02197
```

---

Using `<a href="...">↗&#8599; &#x2197;</a>` the result in Chrome on Macbook is: [image]

and on Chrome/Firefox on Android mobile the result is different: [image]

I want always the char as text so always like that [image].

Answer (score 5):

You need a specific format for this to work on React, you can do the following:

```js
<a href="...">{'\u02197'}</a>
```

You have to use the curly braces to prevent React from formating the string to just HTML content.

Answer (score 4):

Try `String.fromCharCode()` where the argument is the decimal representation of the unicode character (which is hex).

U+02197 would be written as `String.fromCharCode(8599)`

In my case, I needed an up (U+25B2) and down (U+25BC) arrow, so I got it working doing something like this:

```
<span className="direction">
   {String.fromCharCode(this.state.direction === "up" ? 9650 : 9660)}
</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the hex code:

```
<a href="...">&#x2197;&#xFE0E;</a>
```

Source: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2197/index.htm

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work, see my main question, I edit it

Comment: How about adding `font-family:serif !important` in your css?

Comment: I have edited the answer. It work for me. Before that, it show emoji in Microsoft Edge. But after I add `&#xFE0E;` it shows the text version.

Comment: I use BrowserStack to test it and it doesn't work.. I see the emoji instead of the text version